# Is it possible to use aggregate functions in pgAdmin's Graphical Query Builder?

Tags: pgadmin

I was exploring the graphical query builder and I stumbled upon that I couldn't use simple aggregate functions in it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean PgAdmin?  If so, I doubt it.  The graphical query builder is great for starting queries (choosing columns, assigning aliases, etc), but it's not all-encompassing.  For example, I don't think it even handles outer joins...  if it does, it escapes me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you mean PgAdmin? If so, I doubt it. The graphical query builder is great for starting queries (choosing columns, assigning aliases, etc), but it's not all-encompassing. For example, I don't think it even handles outer joins... if it does, it escapes me how to do it. – Hambone